# Understanding width and precision modifier on strings

Tags: bash

I have seen the following line that sets a padding of empty characters.

```
printf -v pad "%${nc}.${nc}s" ' '
```

Is there a valid reason for using both the width modifier and the precision modifier, to a padding composed of `nc` space characters?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a valid reason for using both the width modifier and the precision modifier, to a padding composed of nc space characters?

Padding specifies minimum amount of characters, precision specifies maximum amount of characters. The resulting string will always be exactly `$nc` characters long.

```
$ printf "%2.2s\n" "a" "ab" "abc"
 a
ab
ab
```